# convert unstructured data to structure using awk

Tags: unix, text, awk, sed, gawk

I have a file with the data in the following format:

```
Structure type: 625
Call type: 119
Date: 1 January 2016
Service observed / Traffic sampled : Default
Operator action : Automatically identified, customer dialed
Structure type: 625
Call type: 119
Date: 1 January 2016
Service observed / Traffic sampled : Default
Operator action : Automatically identified, customer dialed
```

I want to convert the following CDR data into a structure to load it into a SQL database:

Expected structure is

```
Structure type|Call type|Date|Service observed/ Traffic sampled|...
625|119|1 January 2016|Default|...
```

I am using the following code -

```
awk 'NR >= 1 { print $1, $3, $5, $7, $9, $11, $13, $15, $17, $19 } { print $2, $4, $6, $8, $10, $12, $14, $16, $18, $20 } ' RS='\n\n' FS=': +|\n' OFS='|'
```

The output is blank. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: how should this line `Trunk Identification : Routing Indicator = Direct - Incoming Different network : Trunk Group Number = 0001 : Trunk Member Number = 0014` be transformed?

Comment: That will be a clob in the data field in Oracle, hence all values after the initail ":" will be the values.

Comment: Post an example that's about 10 lines long rather than 100 and more people will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `awk` command to attain your goal,

```
awk -F ': ' '(/Structure type/ && NR!=1){printf "\n"} {printf "%s|",$2} END{printf "\n"}' file.txt
```

Output:

```
625|119|1 January 2016|Default|Automatically identified, customer dialed|None|000-380-4893|NPA determined by the network element|000-370-9901|04:01:27.1|0:17.3|CIC = 0000 |1 January 2016|04:01:26.8|0:17.5|10|Signaling type not specified |Tandem|CAC not dialed, station not presub, no presub ind|CPN provided|104|Routing Indicator = Direct - Incoming Different network |Final module|
625|119|1 January 2016|Default|Automatically identified, customer dialed|None|000-000-0000|NPA dialed by customer|000-380-5414|03:59:57.5|4:01.9|CIC = 0000 |1 January 2016|03:59:35.5|4:23.9|10|SS7 from IC to AT, SS7 to EO |Tandem|CAC not dialed, station not presub, no presub ind|Neither ANI nor CPN provided|104|Routing Indicator = Direct - Incoming Different network |104|Routing Indicator = Direct - Outgoing Different network |119|Trunk Group Number - Interoffice = 9056 |Network Interface Description = Feature Group D|Administrative Domain = 0 |Final module|
```

Comment: Thanks @CWLiu I am getting the output in a single column instead as a row

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F": " '{a[NR]=$1;$1="";b[NR]=$0;}END{printf "%s",a[1];for(i=2;i<=NR;i++)printf "|%s",a[i]; printf "\n%s",b[1];for(i=2;i<=NR;i++)printf "|%s",b[i];}' filename
```

output:

```
Structure type|Call type|Date|Service observed / Traffic sampled |Operator action |Service feature code|Calling number|Overseas indicator |Called number|Time|Length of call|IC / INC indicator |Carrier connect date|Carrier connect time|Carrier elapsed time|IC/INC call event status |Trunk Group Number |IC / INC Routing Indicator |Dialing and presubscription indicator |ANI / CPN indicator |Module code |Trunk Identification |Module code |Structure type|Call type|Date|Service observed / Traffic sampled |Operator action |Service feature code|Calling number|Overseas indicator |Called number|Time|Length of call|IC / INC indicator |Carrier connect date|Carrier connect time|Carrier elapsed time|IC/INC call event status |Trunk Group Number |IC / INC Routing Indicator |Dialing and presubscription indicator |ANI / CPN indicator |Module code |Trunk Identification |Module code |Trunk Identification |Module code |Trunk Group |Carrier Interface |Remote network ID |Module code 
 625| 119| 1 January 2016| Default| Automatically identified, customer dialed| None| 000-380-4893| NPA determined by the network element| 000-370-9901| 04:01:27.1| 0:17.3| CIC = 0000  CIC unknown, IC/INC involvement unknown| 1 January 2016| 04:01:26.8| 0:17.5| 10| Signaling type not specified  0001| Tandem| CAC not dialed, station not presub, no presub ind| CPN provided| 104| Routing Indicator = Direct - Incoming Different network  Trunk Group Number = 0001  Trunk Member Number = 0014| Final module| 625| 119| 1 January 2016| Default| Automatically identified, customer dialed| None| 000-000-0000| NPA dialed by customer| 000-380-5414| 03:59:57.5| 4:01.9| CIC = 0000  CIC unknown, IC/INC not involved| 1 January 2016| 03:59:35.5| 4:23.9| 10| SS7 from IC to AT, SS7 to EO  0001| Tandem| CAC not dialed, station not presub, no presub ind| Neither ANI nor CPN provided| 104| Routing Indicator = Direct - Incoming Different network  Trunk Group Number = 9056  Trunk Member Number = 0029| 104| Routing Indicator = Direct - Outgoing Different network  Trunk Group Number = 0001  Trunk Member Number = 0063| 119| Trunk Group Number - Interoffice = 9056  Trunk Member Number - Interoffice = 0029  Trunk Member Number - Final = 0063| Network Interface Description = Feature Group D| Administrative Domain = 0  Network Number = 000000| Final module
```

Comment: thanks - the header row comes out beautiful however the values are printed vertically downwards, as one column instead of being a row...

Comment: copied it, should i type it out?

Comment: nope. it must work. in your file after : there is just space, yep?

Comment: Yes there is, only one space character after the :

Comment: damn, i only use newline when i start print b array, where i store values. so values will be row as well

Comment: cygwin may be reason, but strange. u can test my code work http://awk.js.org/ (just copy code without awk and filename and in stdin your file data)

Comment: Yes it works in the editor, any solution to this? After 625 there is a carriage return; and every "|" is on a separate line

Comment: damn, strange printf "|%s",b[i]; does not use new line, if use only print it will use, but not printf.

Comment: Try running `dos2unix` on your input first to get rid of those CRs. They're almost certainly appearing in the output because they're present in the input before each LF.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F' *: *' '{ h=(h=="")? $1 : h"|"$1; sub(/^[^:]+ *: */,"",$0); v=(v=="")? $0 : v"|"$0 }
               END { print h ORS v }' file
```

The output:

```
Structure type|Call type|Date|Service observed / Traffic sampled|Operator action|Service feature code|Calling number|Overseas indicator|Called number|Time|Length of call|IC / INC indicator|Carrier connect date|Carrier connect time|Carrier elapsed time|IC/INC call event status|Trunk Group Number|IC / INC Routing Indicator|Dialing and presubscription indicator|ANI / CPN indicator|Module code|Trunk Identification|Module code|Structure type|Call type|Date|Service observed / Traffic sampled|Operator action|Service feature code|Calling number|Overseas indicator|Called number|Time|Length of call|IC / INC indicator|Carrier connect date|Carrier connect time|Carrier elapsed time|IC/INC call event status|Trunk Group Number|IC / INC Routing Indicator|Dialing and presubscription indicator|ANI / CPN indicator|Module code|Trunk Identification|Module code|Trunk Identification|Module code|Trunk Group|Carrier Interface|Remote network ID|Module code
625|119|1 January 2016|Default|Automatically identified, customer dialed|None|000-380-4893|NPA determined by the network element|000-370-9901|04:01:27.1|0:17.3|CIC = 0000 : CIC unknown, IC/INC involvement unknown|1 January 2016|04:01:26.8|0:17.5|10|Signaling type not specified : 0001|Tandem|CAC not dialed, station not presub, no presub ind|CPN provided|104|Routing Indicator = Direct - Incoming Different network : Trunk Group Number = 0001 : Trunk Member Number = 0014|Final module|625|119|1 January 2016|Default|Automatically identified, customer dialed|None|000-000-0000|NPA dialed by customer|000-380-5414|03:59:57.5|4:01.9|CIC = 0000 : CIC unknown, IC/INC not involved|1 January 2016|03:59:35.5|4:23.9|10|SS7 from IC to AT, SS7 to EO : 0001|Tandem|CAC not dialed, station not presub, no presub ind|Neither ANI nor CPN provided|104|Routing Indicator = Direct - Incoming Different network : Trunk Group Number = 9056 : Trunk Member Number = 0029|104|Routing Indicator = Direct - Outgoing Different network : Trunk Group Number = 0001 : Trunk Member Number = 0063|119|Trunk Group Number - Interoffice = 9056 : Trunk Member Number - Interoffice = 0029 : Trunk Member Number - Final = 0063|Network Interface Description = Feature Group D|Administrative Domain = 0 : Network Number = 000000|Final module
```